# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR | Full aplication (back + front)

Tags: node.js, vue.js

**DESCRIPTION**

This is my first online project and it consist in Vuejs (frontend framework), nodeJs (backend) and mongoDB (database NoSQL).

I'm hosting front in Hostinger, backend also in Hostinger using VPS and MongoDB in MongoDB Atlas.

All frontend, backend and database are working fine, using Localhost or Insomnia/Postman. The CRUD is working well

**PROBLEM**

It is when I try to access the information from Backend using the real website application.

When I try to do an auth, I got two errors on console:

```
POST https://89.116.225.159:5000/api/auth/login net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

**CODE**

This is the code where the fetch does not work. But as I said above, in localhost and inside Imsomnia using the same http path are working just fine

```
await fetch("http://89.116.225.159:5000/api/auth/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
    body: jsonDataObject
})
```

**APP**
This is the app that I created. It is just for training;
https://routehelper.com.br/

If you want, you can try to do a login to see the error.
user: vitin@hotmail.com
password: mudar123

I have already tried to clear cache, SSL state and adjust the time and date on my computer. Things that I found on internet, but the error still there.

Anyone knows what it could be?

----------------------------edited----------------------------------

**BACKEND LOGIN**

> server.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

// routes
const authRouter = require("./routes/authRoutes");

// config
const dbName = "databaseRoutering"
const port = 5000;

const DB_USER = process.env.DB_USER
const DB_PASS = process.env.DB_PASS

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use("/api/auth", authRouter)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Rota teste"})
})

// mongoDB connection
mongoose.connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@cluster0.06ovsjg.mongodb.net/users?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Nossa variável ${process.env.MY_VARIABLE}`)
    console.log(`backend rodando na porta ${port}`)
})
```

> authRoutes.js

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const User = require("../models/user");

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });

    if(!user){
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Não há um usuário cadastrado com esse email!" })
    }

    // check if password match
    const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if(!checkPassword){
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Senha Inválida!"});
    }

    // create token
    const token = jwt.sign(
        {
            name: user.name,
            id: user._id
        },
        "oursecret"
    );

    // return token
    res.json({ error: null, msg: "Você está autenticado!", 
        token: token, 
        userId: user._id, 
        firstName: user.firstName, 
        lastName: user.lastName, 
        email: user.email,
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

**FRONTEND**

```
methods: {
        changeToRegister() {
                this.$store.commit('changeToRegister')
        },
        async loginVerification(e) {
            // it does not let the page reaload
            e.preventDefault();
            // it creates the object that will be use on API
            const dataObject = {
                email: this.auth.email,
                password: this.auth.password
            }
            const jsonDataObject = JSON.stringify(dataObject)
            await fetch("http://89.116.225.159:5000/api/auth/login", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
                body: jsonDataObject
            })
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            // it access the api to update the profile data using token and the object
            .then((data) => {
                if(data.error){
                    // it prints the error
                    this.returnMessage = data.error;
                } else {
                    // it takes to the dashboard page and commit all the page with the user info
                    this.$router.push({ path: '/ClientPage' })
                    this.$store.commit("authenticate", {
                        token: data.token, 
                        userId: data.userId, 
                        firstName: data.firstName, 
                        lastName: data.lastName,
                        email: data.email,
                    })
                }
            })
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some config or infra redirecting your http request to https which is failing because you likely either don't have HTTPS configured or you should be using the domain name instead of the IP as SSL requires a domain name to work(most of the time).

Comment: yes, i am almost sure that you said it is the problem. It should be 'http post' and not 'https post' as console is showing me. 

But i don not know why it is changing it ;)

Comment: I forgot to mention! To up my backend to the cloud, it was used PM2

Comment: Unless you have more information to post its up to you to figure out where this redirection is occurring.

Comment: Yes, I edited my question above with more information. However, I think the problem is the way that I put it up my backend online, with PM2. I think using PM2 always will be http only! This is the 'GET' message that I created first to test the VPS - http://89.116.225.159:5000/ - But it is a guess only